# aspx application working perfectly on localhost but not in online server

Tags: c#, asp.net

After spending hours still can not find my issue. I am working on asp.net application in which i need to populate options of dropdown controll by code behind file it is pupulating excellent on my localhost but when i am checking it on online website its not working. the page shows dropdown box without any options.

**AspxFile**

```
 <%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" EnableEventValidation="true" Inherits="Acc.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    About
</h2>
<p>
    Put content here.
</p>
<form runat="server">
<div>
<asp:DropDownList id="modelItem" runat="server">
 <asp:ListItem>Select </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
 </div>
<div>
<asp:DropDownList id="ddl_update" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem>Select </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</form>

</asp:Content>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Acc
{
  public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AccDataContext db = new AccDataContext();
        var acc = from m in db.acs select m;
        foreach (var item in acc)
        {
            ListItem n = new ListItem();
            n.Text = item.title.Trim();
            n.Value = item.acode.Trim();
            modelItem.Items.Add(n);
            ddl_update.Items.Add(n);
        }
    }
    }
 }
```

**DesignerFile**

```
namespace Acc {


public partial class About {

    /// <summary>
    /// modelItem control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList modelItem;

    /// <summary>
    /// ddl_update control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList ddl_update;
}
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Can you see your web page? Are you getting an error? Where's the problem? What's happeneinginginging?

Comment: You need to give more details about what is not working.

Comment: @Shannon Holsinger ,Joel Lee  I am not getting any error message its just showing dropdownlist box without options. which i need to populate from codebehind

Comment: do you really need this line `EnableEventValidation="true"` also I wonder if it is working but it's calling this `Page_Load` twice try putting some `If(!IsPostBackCode)` code or store the data in a session variable then bind the dropdown from the session object..

Comment: Are the items in the listbox when you open it? I don't see where you've set selectedindex=0 or set selected=true for your SELECT listitem

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger no the items not showing in the list box on online website but items shows in my localhost machine perfectly

Comment: What about your db connection string. Is it trying to connect to a local DB? If so, you'd need to change your connection string to reflect the different location of the DB.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger sorry but i am new in asp.net. is it necessary to mention selectedindex=0 or selected=true because i am not using it in other pages where i need to use dropdown list but its working great

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger i am not working on localdatabase i am directly use hosted database. so there is no need to change connection string.

Comment: That's not your problem here if the items aren't listed when you open the dropbox. Just for fun & games, try checking the count of acc and modelItem.Items.Count.ToString() after the method runs - see how many you are getting back from DB

Comment: @MethodMan not working after deleting EnableEventValidation. can you elaborate you question can not understand your suggestion about session

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger ok i checked localhost shows 105 items but when i upload my page and check online I am not getting any count string

Comment: So, that tells us that the problem isn't in the ASPX page or the itemlist, but in the database connection. Have you verified your connection to the database? Is it (the connection) working elsewhere when you upload to remote site?

Comment: the only problem seems to be that you cant connect to your db. do this check if (acc==null || acc.Count==0){ Response.write("acc is empty");}